# URL.Action does not generate URL correctly in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC web application

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

I have a web application divided into some modules. One of those modules is called `Authenticate` (which contains all authentication implementations of the whole application).

I have a login page which is accessed using this URL:

```
https://localhost:44375/Authenticate/Security/Login
```

Where `Authenticate` is the name of the module, `Security` is the controller and `Login` is the action.

Inside the corresponding view, `Login.cshtml`, I have this markup:

```
@Url.Action("Login", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })'
```

That code generates the URL this way:

```
/Authenticate/Authenticate/Security/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F
```

If I add the controller in the `Url.Action` code, this way:

```
@Url.Action("Login", "Security", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
```

the same happens.

How can I solve it? For some reason, the module name is duplicated in the actual URL that is created.

Thanks

Jaime

Comment: what is `module` in your question, Does it mean [Area](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-7.0) ?

Comment: @XinranShen Similar tu Area, conceptually, but it is implemented in different assembly.

Comment: can't reproduce your issue, could you provide a minimal executed demo?

Comment: To make an example, I should upload a whole project somewhere, because this problem occurs only when I devide the web application into more than 1 assembly. As a patch, I created an extension method that removes the first part of the path, but it depends on where page the user is in, how `Url.Action` behaves. For example, if the web page that is shown is  managed by the entry point assembly, `Url.Action` works, however, if the displayed web page is managed by other assembly, `Url.Action` prepend the URL with the assembly name. I could try to create a sample project and upload to Github.

Comment: @XinranShen I created,a test project. You can see it in https://github.com/jaimestuardo/MultiAssemblyWeb. When executed, the top menu in home page will have 2 options: Other Home and Other Privacy. Both options belongs to OtherAssembly. Please see the links of those options. I have prepended "Other" to the URL because they belongs to a controller in other assembly. Now, please, click on one of those options, for example, `Other Home`.

Comment: Then see the links. You will see the link as `/Other/Other/Privacy` bacause, since I am in the context of the other assembly, the call to `Url.Action` prepend the `Other` part automatically. That prepending does not occur when the browser is in the entry point assembly. I am thinking that I could make an extension that detects if browser is in a module page. If it is, `Url.Action` is used as it is. If is not, I manually prepend module name. Could this be a good solution or do you think about another way?

Comment: @XinranShen Finally I solved the problem. Please see the answer if you want to comment anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I created the following extension method:

```
    public static string ModuleAction(this IUrlHelper urlHelper, string action, string controller, string module, object? values = null)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(urlHelper);

        var oldPathBase = urlHelper.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.PathBase;
        urlHelper.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.PathBase = oldPathBase.Value == $"/{module}" ? new PathString() : new PathString($"/{module}");
        var url = urlHelper.Action(action, controller, values) ?? string.Empty;
        urlHelper.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.PathBase = oldPathBase;
        return url;
    }
```

Since `Action` method uses `PathBase` to get the first part of the link, I am changing it momentarily to use the path corresponding to the module.

What I am not sure, why I needed to use the `oldPathBase.Value == $"/{module}"` check. If I am browsing a page in the same module I am generating the URL to, `Action` method already includes the module path prepended.

Consider, for example, the logout link, present in every page in the site, should be:

> https://server/authenticate/security/logout

That URL is generated by a call to `Url.ModuleAction("Logout", "Security", "Authenticate")` in the view.

If I didn´t use that check, the generated URL was `https://server/authenticate/authenticate/security/logout`

If someone can explain why that happens, please comment.

You can see a sample project at https://github.com/jaimestuardo/MultiAssemblyWeb.